# Can't consume messages from topic partitions in ClickHouse

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

I am introducing with kafka and I want to know how can I consume mesages from partitions in topic to ClickHouse tables like this: 
[image]

In case when I have 3 topics it was easy to connect tables on each topics

```
ENGINE = Kafka SETTINGS
  kafka_broker_list = 'broker:9092',
  kafka_topic_list = 'topic1',
  kafka_group_name = 'kafka_group',
  kafka_format = 'JSONEachRow'
```

But I don't know how to consume messages from partitions of one topic to tables. Please help

Comment: Why don't you just use multiple topics if you have different data in different partitions? Like topic1table1, topic1table2, topic1table3? Or it's a matter of using 'closest' partition in the multiserver scenario?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do that

1. Keep the identifier in your message like below. In your consumer you can read table attribute and take decision in which table you have to save the data.

   {
     table: Table1
   }
2. Though kafka don't provide any direct way to produce method to specific partition however you can use key for that. Lets make the key with three value 1,2,3. When message is produced for Table1 use key 1. That way message will go to only one partition and then consumer for that partition can save data in Table1

Personally I'll prefer method 1 as it don't couple kafka processing with your business logic

Comment: thank you, but I need to split topic on ClickHouse part